# How do I mark mail as read in Lotus Notes without actually opening the email?

Tags: email, lotus-notes

How do I mark mail as read in Lotus Notes without actually opening the email?  Every other email client I have used has this option somewhere.  I am using Lotus Notes 8.  Thank you.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Select your email messages and under `Edit -> Unread Marks -> Mark Selected Read` will do it.

*Update*

Pulled up comment from @Leons

Under Notes 8.5, you can make the behavior default in:

```
File > Preferences > Basic Notes Client Config
```

and check the box in the `Additional Options` list box:

```
[x] Mark documents read when opened in preview pane
```

Answer (score 18):

You can also hit the insert key to toggle read status.

Comment: On a mac you can type Shift+Command+U to toggle the read status.

Comment: My new lenovo doesn't have the insert button :( any thoughts?

Answer (score 15):

The best way is to go to Preferences > Basic Notes Client Configuration > Additional Options > Mark documents read when opened in preview pane.

Comment: This should really be the accepted response.

Answer (score 4):

In **Lotus Notes 9** (I'm pretty sure it's the same as 8)

**File -> Preferences...**

[image: File, Preferences]

**Basic Notes Client Configuration ->  Mark documents read when opened...**

[image: Basic Notes Client Configuration, Mark documents read when opened]

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using Lotus Notes 8.5: Select multiple emails -> Right Click -> Mark As -> Read. Please note a check tick mark will be shown for all the selected emails.